# How can a I create a field on my class that's autoincremented from zero to 255

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

to create a sequence on JPA I normaly use this 
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@SequenceGenerator(name="example_sequence", sequenceName="example_sequence")

But I want to create a sequence that is also generated automatically but it increments from 0 to 255 and when this value is acheived it restarts from zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will need to create your own sequence generator

http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/SequenceGenerator

http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.1.0/docs/jpa_overview_mapping_sequence.html

http://blog.cyclopsgroup.org/2007/04/custom-idgenerator-for-jpa-gap-between.html

Comment: The column that I need to use this generator will not be unique because of the restart value and it's not my primary key, so I shouldn't have any problems with the sequence generator

Comment: Yes it helped but I'm taking a beating, its not really clear form me how to implement the generator do you have any example on setting the max value on the generator and reseting it